# Convert string with encoded character to readable string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, string, character-encoding

An API is returning string with special characters in this form:
"Universit\xc3\xa0 di Parma" 
\xc3\xa0 means the character "à"

How can I convert this string into a readable form with JavaScript code?
Thank you !

Input: "Universit\xc3\xa0 di Parma"

Desidered output: "Università di Parma"

Comment: Is it doubly escaped i.e. `\\xc3\\xa0`? Otherwise, there is no need to "decode" it.

Comment: no the string it not double escaped.

Comment: Then you don't need to decode it. Run `console.log("Universit\xc3\xa0 di Parma")` and see for yourself.

Comment: with your command I obtain "UniversitÃ di Parma" insted of "Università di Parma"

Comment: `\xc3\xa0` is "Ã", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) method with decodeURIComponent.

```js
const original = 'Universit\xc3\xa0 di Parma';
const result = decodeURIComponent(escape(original));
console.log(result);
```